# How do I capture a word boundary but ignore spaces in the word?

Tags: regex, word-boundary

**Example**: "Price of BTC on Bit finex"

**Regex I tried:** `\b(bitfinex)\b`

The regex above captures `bitfinex` if the word has no spaces anywhere in it. how do I account zero or more spaces between any letters in the word boundary without capturing those spaces

I tried `\b(b\s*i\s*t\s*f\s*i\s*n\s*e\s*x)\b` but it returns match as `Bit finex`, how do I ignore the spaces and get it as `bitfinex`

Any direction is appreciated

Comment: Remove all spaces right after a match, there is no other good way to achieve that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so you are saying that it cannot be done within the regex and i have to do a string.replace('\s*', '') on each item after I get the matches

Answer (score 3):

theoretically: put every letter inside a capture group and return only the capture groups.

realistically?: take two steps. Match the regex with spaces, and replace spaces in a second step